# Slow assembly using a large include file in MASM

Tags: c, assembly, masm

Recently split a large MASM project consisting of 50 included assembly files into separate translation units. However, the assembly time increased from 1 min to 10 mins! The reason for this dramatic increase was tracked down to a LARGE include file with 60,000 constants (built from parsing Windows/Linux C header files for constants, then massaged into the MASM syntax)

**WindowsLinux.inc**

```
ERROR_SUCCESS                                       EQU       0
ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION                              EQU       1
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                EQU       2
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND                                EQU       3
ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES                           EQU       4
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED                                 EQU       5
...
```

For example, created this simple timing test when including **WindowsLinux.inc** for the constant ERROR_SUCCESS

**slow.asm**

```
option casemap:none

extrn printf:proc

IFDEF SLOW
   include WindowsLinux.inc
ELSE
   ERROR_SUCCESS EQU 0
ENDIF

.data

     szError db 'ERROR_SUCCESS = %d',0ah,0
     
.code

main proc
     mov     rdx,ERROR_SUCCESS
     mov     rcx,offset szError
     call    printf  
    
     ret
     
main endp

end
```

Assembled **slow.asm** passing a defined text macro **/DSLOW** to include **WindowsLinux.inc**

```
@ECHO %TIME%
ml64.exe /DSLOW /c slow.asm
@ECHO %TIME%
```

The output below shows it took ~ 8 seconds.

> 9:15:52.17
>
> C:\masm32>ml64.exe /DSLOW /c slow.asm
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.29.30146.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: slow.asm
>
> 9:15:59.43

Reassembled **slow.asm** removing the defined text macro **/DSLOW**

```
@ECHO %TIME%
ml64.exe /c slow.asm
@ECHO %TIME%
```

The output below shows it took ~ 3 milliseconds.

> 9:35:55.12
>
> C:\masm32>ml64.exe /c slow.asm
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.29.30146.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: slow.asm
>
> 9:35:55.15

To resolve the slow include file issue, the number of constants was reduced from 60,000 to 250.
However, this requires constantly updating the include file each time a new constant is added to the source code. Perhaps there's a better approach?

**Question**

Do any assemblers have a similar concept to C/C++ [Precompiled headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) which can  significantly reduce compilation time?

Comment: NASM has an `incbin` directive which copies a binary file into the output at the current position.  IDK if MASM has anything similar.  Of course that's not helpful for macro definitions and stuff.